# SQL view, where clause

Tags: sql, date, where-clause

So I am writing a 'view' for a SQL database to track lead water testing in public schools.

One of the views the client would like is to be able to recall data when a facility has an active date that is the current date.

The tables and fields I am working with include `Facility.FacilityID` from `FacilityLocation` where `FacilityLocation` is active (the range between `FacilityLocation.ActiveFrom` and `Facility.ActiveTo` includes present date.

I am trying to figure out how to only call facilities that are presently active.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE VIEW facility_view AS
    Select FacilityID
    From FacilityLocation
    Where FacilityLocation = 'active' And ...
```

How do I go about including the `ActiveFrom` and `ActiveTo` fields into this view?

Comment: How about `BETWEEN`?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: it is MSSQL 2012, that is what the client is using.

Answer (score 0):

Add another condition

```
and (ActiveFrom >= some_date and ActiveTo < some_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

and activefrom >= 'dd/mm/yy' and activeTo < 'dd/mm/yy'